# Get argument count (or even names) of javascript function object

Tags: javascript, function, object

I want to evaluate callback function before accepting it. This means I need to know at least the count of accepted argumens - if count doesn't match, I'll leave warning in console. 
But I can't find out, whether a javascript function object has a property that would help me get that information.
So can this be achieved **without** parsing function as string (not worth it)?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

A function has [a `length` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length) which tells you how many *named* arguments it accepts. Note however, a function can use the `arguments` variable to access variables, even if it doesn't name them; `length` doesn't cater for this (nor is there an alternative which does).

```
function foo(a, b) {
    for (var i=0;i<arguments.length;i++) {
        console.log(arguments[i]);
    }
}

console.log(foo.length); // reports 2, even though `foo` can access all your arguments!
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a full specification of function object properties and methods? I failed to find one.

Comment: @Tomas: the link in my answer should provide this.

Comment: NOTE: default parameters don't count to `length`. Check yourself:
`[((a) => {}), ((a=1) => {})].forEach(f => console.log(\`f="${f.toString()}", length=${f.length}\`))`