# How does Mocha know to be async?

Tags: javascript, function, mocha.js

Mocha can determine whether to expect a callback (`done`), or whether it should run a test in sync, solely based off of you passing the callback as a parameter.

```
// Sync
it("should be amazing", function (){
    expect(amazing).equals(true);
});

// Async
it("should be amazing, eventually", function (done) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    expect(amazing).equals(true);
    done();
  }, 1000);
});
```

I don't know how it does this. The only way I can think is that it literally parses the function as a string, breaks it down and determines if a parameter is passed.

Is this what happens?

Comment: It knows whether or not you've defined the function to take an argument (e.g. `done`)

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18422560/1267663

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wouldn't expect it, but functions have a [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length) property! It is equal to the number of arguments the function takes.

<s>I'll edit the answer to add a snippet out of mocha when I find it</s>, but that's a valid way that it can detect whether or not it accepts an argument. Check the length for if it's one, that decides whether or not the test is async or not.

**Edit:** [I found it.](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/6183ec73280e25ab490a6a2a1235ccdd3db19953/lib/runnable.js#L48) For context, `it` inherits from `Runnable`.

```
function Runnable(title, fn) {
    // Other properties...
    this.async = fn && fn.length;
    // Other properties...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It uses either a string parser on the callback or an argument length check.

Something like this

```
function it(name, callback) {

   if (callback.length > 0) {
      callback(function done(e) {
          if (e) throw "test finished with error"
          //test finished
      })

   } else {
       callback()
       //test finished
   }
}
```